# Error loading Egg-Fu, crashes whilst starting Eggdrop

Tags: tcl, irc, eggdrop

I'm trying to follow the LinuxFormat Guide to creating an IRC bot on the Raspberry Pi. I got everything working (Eggdrop and Hybrid loaded flawlessly), but when I tried to install Egg-Fu, I got this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/eggdrop $ ./eggdrop -m eggdrop.simple.conf

Eggdrop v1.6.9 (C) 1997 Robey Pointer (C) 2002 Eggheads
[23:24] --- Loading eggdrop v1.6.9 (Sun Aug 10 2014)
[23:24] Module loaded: dns
[23:24] Module loaded: channels
[23:24] Module loaded: server
[23:24] Module loaded: ctcp
[23:24] Module loaded: irc
[23:24] Module loaded: notes            (with lang support)
[23:24] Module loaded: console          (with lang support)
[23:24] Module loaded: blowfish
[23:24] Listening at telnet port 3334 (all)
[23:24] Module loaded: uptime
[23:24] Userinfo TCL v1.07 loaded (URL BF GF IRL EMAIL DOB PHONE ICQ).
[23:24] use '.help userinfo' for commands.
[23:24] Tcl error in file 'eggdrop.simple.conf':
[23:24] error reading "file20": illegal operation on a directory
while executing
"gets $bc"
    invoked from within
"set sex [gets $bc]"
    (file "/home/pi/eggdrop/scripts/egg-fu_2.0.11.tcl" line 761)
    invoked from within
"source /home/pi/eggdrop/scripts/egg-fu_2.0.11.tcl"
    (file "eggdrop.simple.conf" line 146)
[23:24] * CONFIG FILE NOT LOADED (NOT FOUND, OR ERROR)
```

Why is this happening?.

Comment: Your conf file is misconfigured: egg-fu is trying to open a **directory** and read text from it.

Comment: Of all the things! I didn't realise that you had to set a path to a **FILE** for the birth certificate - I thought it would auto-name! Thanks!